# gcc preprocessor __DATE__ and __TIME__ print to terminal

Tags: gcc, terminal, preprocessor

I use in the code;

```
const char compileDate[]      = {__DATE__};
const char compileTime[]      = {__TIME__};
```

but I can only see these values when I run the program. Is is possible see the date and time values just after compilation? I would like to make something like this:

```
gcc main.c
date&time: "29 Feb 2018 16:32:55"
a.out created
```

Of course date and time in the code and in the terminal output must be the same.

Comment: Not possible.   The compiler can't be coerced to print out date and time in that format (say, to screen) based on `__DATE__` and `__TIME__`.  And any means of getting data and time from outside the compiler (e.g. in a makefile) will get a different time, since it will be run after the compiler has finished.   The most you can do is ensure your program has a command line option to print its build time, and run your program with that option immediately after building it.

Comment: I am cross compiling.

Comment: Have the makefile keep track of date/time information, and pass it to the compiler as a macro (which then allows your program to use it).   You won't be able to use `__DATE__` and `__TIME__` though - since they will not give the same results for date/time as in the makefile.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the compiler to do it but you could do it with an external script, defining your own macros to use instead of `__TIME__` and `__DATE__`

For instance, in UNIX shell:

```
date '+%b %e %Y %I:%M:%S' >xxx
cat xxx xxx | sed -n -e '1s/^\(...........\).*/#define MY_DATE "\1"/p' -e '2s/.*\(........\)$/#define MY_TIME "\1"/p' > xxx.h
cat xxx
```

will print the date `Oct 27 2023 09:37:48`, and also create a header file, xxx.h, which contains

```
#define MY_DATE "Oct 27 2023"
#define MY_TIME "09:37:48"
```

which can then be used by your code.